# Shopclues API Error while generating manifest

Tags: node.js, api, meteor

I am trying to process an order using shopclues open API . I am making request to create auto order manifest API,I am getting success response from their server but my order is not processed.

Response I get :

```html
{
  "status": 1,
  "code": 200,
  "message": "success",
  "data": {
    "special_message": "Success orders array: \nnull\n\nAssign awbno by DSS orders array: \n[]\n\nPartial orders array: \n[105239427]\n\n. NSS orders array: \n[]\n\n. Unauthorised Item id array: \n[95089406]",
    "dss_orders": null,
    "partial_orders": [
      105239427
    ],
    "nss_orders": [],
    "unauthorised_item": [
      95089406
    ],
    "order_ids_without_awbno": null
  },
  "extra": null
}
```

It gives "**unauthorised item id**"

Anyone with any idea please help

Thanks in Advance.